# Join a table to itself with no specfic ID

Tags: sql

Join a table to itself with no specfic ID

I have a table of customer records which has no ID column, a customer may appear in the table more than once with various of the columns populated.  I have managed to build a column INIT_SURNAME which is fully poplated but not unique to a customer.  How can I merge the rows for matching customers where they have the same INIT_SURNAME and share one other common data element. For example I want to return 3 cutomers from the following table, the 1st 3 rows are the same person.

e.g

INPUT:

```
INIT_SURNAME|EMAIL|PHONE|OTHERID
J*SOAP|js@x.com|4321|
J*SOAP|js@x.com||
J*SOAP||4321|4
J*SOAP|otherjoe@y.com||2
J*DOE||12345|3
```

Output:

```
INIT_SURNAME|EMAIL|PHONE|OTHERID
J*SOAP|js@x.com|4321|4
J*SOAP|otherjoe@y.com||2
J*DOE||12345|3
```

Can this be done?

Comment: What do you want to happen if one of the other columns matches, but a different one doesn't match? For example, init_surname and email match, but the phone is different? Is it a match? Which phone should be returned?

Answer (score 1):

You could merge each column separately.

Example code in T-Sql:

```
declare @foo table ( 
    name varchar(30), 
    email varchar(30), 
    phone varchar(30), 
    id varchar(30)
)
insert into @foo values 
('J*SOAP','js@x.com','4321',NULL),
('J*SOAP','js@x.com',NULL,NULL),
('J*SOAP',NULL,'4321','4'),
('J*SOAP','otherjoe@y.com',NULL,'2'),
('J*DOE',NULL,'12345','3')

;with 
merge_by_email as (
    select name, email, MAX(phone) as phone, MAX(id) as id 
    from @foo 
    group by name, email
),
merge_by_phone as (
    select name, max(email) as email, phone, MAX(id) as id 
    from merge_by_email 
    group by name, phone
),
merge_by_id as (
    select name, max(email) as email, MAX(phone) as phone, id 
    from merge_by_phone 
    group by name, id
)
select * from merge_by_id
```